# Find prime numbers satisfying an equation

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations, pythagorean-triples

Find all triplets $(m, n, p)$, where $p$ is a prime number and $m, n ∈ \Bbb N$, such that

$p=\frac{m}{4}\sqrt{{2n-m \over 2n+m}}$

My procedure is as follows:

$p=\frac{m}{4}{\sqrt{(2n)^2-m^2}\over 2n+m}$

It can be shown that m cannot be odd, so if $m=2k$,

$p=\frac{k}{2}{\sqrt{n^2-k^2}\over n+k}$

If $l=\sqrt{n^2-k^2}$ then $(k,l,n)$ form a Pythagorean triplet giving the two equations

$p=\frac{kl}{2(n+k)}, k^2+l^2=n^2$

I do not know how to proceed after this. Using a python script, I think the only solutions are $(24,15,2),(24,20,3)$ and $(30,39,5)$. How do I prove this?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the python script? and where is the question from?

Comment: @WasuChanyasubkit the question is from a number theory course worksheet. The code is here: [link](https://github.com/Pranav-PJ/python/blob/main/question.py)

Comment: This question was also asked on an [AoPS thread](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c260h3092072p30239866), but no solution yet.

Comment: $$4p=m\sqrt{\frac{2n-m}{2n+m}}$$
Squaring gives:
$$16p^2=m^2\frac{2n-m}{2n+m}$$
The LHS is 16 mod 96( as all primes greater than 3 are squared to be 1 mod 24. So therefore, so is the RHS. Let m be even we then have:
$$4p^2=k^2\frac{2n-m}{2n+m}$$ which is $$4p^2=k^2\frac{2(n-k)}{2(n+k)}=k^2\frac{n-k}{n+k}$$
Or put another way $$4p^2=k^2\left(1-\frac{2k}{n+k}\right )$$

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee where are you going with this?

Comment: I was hoping for a different approach. But i put it as a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: You can get displayed equations by enclosing them in double instead of single dollar signs. This is particularly relevant for legibility if you mix fractions and exponents.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $m$ and $n$ be positive integers, and $p$ a prime number, such that
$$p=\frac{m}{4}\sqrt{\frac{2n-m}{2n+m}}.$$
Then squaring and clearing denominators yields
$$16p^2(2n+m)=m^2(2n-m).$$
Note that $m$ is even, say $m=2k$ for some positive integer $k$, and so
$$4p^2(n+k)=k^2(n-k).$$
Let $d:=\gcd(k,n)$ so that $k=da$ and $n=db$ with $\gcd(a,b)=1$. Then also
$$4p^2(b+a)=d^2a^2(b-a).\tag{1}$$
Of course $a^2$ is coprime to $b+a$ and so $a^2$ divides $4p^2$, meaning that $a$ divides $2p$. That is to say $a\in\{1,2,p,2p\}$.

- If $a=1$ then equation $(1)$ reduces to
  $$4p^2(b+1)=d^2(b-1).$$
  Of course $\gcd(b+1,b-1)$ divides $2$, so they are either both perfect squares, or both twice perfect squares. The former is impossible as no two perfect squares differ by $2$. In the latter case we easily find that $b=1$, but then the right hand side vanishes, a contradiction.
- If $a=2$ then equation $(1)$ reduces to
  $$p^2(b+2)=d^2(b-2).$$
  Now $\gcd(b+2,b-2)=1$ because $b$ is odd, and so $b+2$ and $b-2$ are both perfect squares. As before this again easily implies that $b=2$, but then the right hand side vanishes again, a contradiction.
- If $a=p$ then equation $(1)$ reduces to
  $$4(b+p)=d^2(b-p),$$
  where $p$ does not divide $b$ because $\gcd(a,b)=1$. We see that $d>2$, and we can rearrange the above to
  $$(d^2+4)p=(d^2-4)b,$$
  where $p$ divides $d^2-4=(d+2)(d-2)$. If $p$ divides $d+2$ then $d-2$ divides $d^2+4$, and hence also
  $$d^2+4=(d-2)(d+2)+8,$$
  and so $d\in\{1,3,4,6,10\}$. If $p$ divides $d-2$ then similarly $d+2$ divides $8$ and so $d\in\{2,6\}$. Either way we see that $d\in\{3,4,6,10\}$, as we already noted that $d>2$. Correspondingly we get
  \begin{eqnarray}
  13p&=&5b\qquad\text{ and so }\qquad (m,n,p)&=&(30,39,5),\\
  20p&=&12b\qquad\text{ and so }\qquad (m,n,p)&=&(24,20,3)\\
  40p&=&32b,&&\\
  104p&=&96b,&&
  \end{eqnarray}
  and the latter two do not have solutions with $p$ prime.
- If $a=2p$ then equation $(1)$ reduces to
  $$b+2p=d^2(b-2p).$$
  Note that $b$ is odd because $\gcd(a,b)=1$, hence also $d$ is odd. We can rearrange the above to
  $$2(d^2+1)p=(d^2-1)b.$$
  The right hand side is divisible by $8$ because $d$ is odd.  The left hand side is then also divisible by $8$, which forces $p=2$. Then we are left with
  $$b+4=(b-4)d^2,$$
  from which we easily conclude that $b=5$ and $d=3$, yielding $(m,n,p)=(24,15,2)$.